# Is there any way of getting rid of the not commonly downloaded alert in IE9?

Tags: internet-explorer-9, download

Is there any way of getting rid of the not commonly downloaded alert in IE9?  Snarky replies are welcome.

Comment: Please, check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21307833/125264
Should help.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommended it, but you can add site to trusted site zone and disable the smart screen filter for that zone. This should disable reputation checking.