# "This file is not commonly downloaded" for zip archive in Firefox

Tags: php, firefox, download, zip, warnings

My web service provide downloading copies of websites from web archive. I noticed that FF users get warning "This file is not commonly downloaded"

[image: error message]

even for ZIP archive containing only HTML files. Tried to change ZIP to 7Zip - didn't help.
Example of ZIP: http://otrto321.archiveorg.download/otrto321.zip

Comment: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/cant-download-or-save-files

Comment: So, what is your actual question? And please don’t say something rather naive like “I want to suppress that warning” now ... if that was possible, the “bad guys” that are actually trying to do harm to users with malicious downloads obviously would do the very same thing then, which means the mechanism would be pointless to begin with ...

Comment: Of course i  want  to suppress that warning, i didn't see it before, when I download ZIP archives from other websites, html templates for example

Comment: I am having this problem too from my github.io page, very eager to find a fix. The linked Firefox article is of no help. The issue seems to be a Microsoft Windows one - https://stackoverflow.com/a/12232722/1828637