# Laravel file download "file not commonly downloaded"

Tags: php, laravel

I am having some issues with file downloads with Laravel. I pretty sure this has nothing to do with Laravel. The problem is that when I try to download a file that I uploaded it gives a warning that the "file is not commonly downloaded". I am not sure why that is happening. Here is my code.

**Download**

```
public function show($id)
{
    $download = Download::findOrFail($id);
    return Storage::download(Download::FILES_DIRECTORY . '/' . $download->file);
}
```

**Upload**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'file' => 'required|file|max:40000'
    ]);

    $file = $request->file('file');
    $fileName = Str::random(30) . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    Storage::putFileAs(Download::FILES_DIRECTORY, $file, $fileName);

    $download = new Download();
    $download->file = $fileName;
    $download->save();

    return back()->with('success', 'File uploaded.');
}
```

**Request headers**

```
Host: ionclient.xyz
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://ionclient.xyz/dashboard
Cookie: XSRF- TOKEN=eyJpdiI6Ik9nQUJCODlDcnpGcDVQXC9meHNNRlF3PT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IkllNlpybkZ2bXZwQytYcG00MzFqa2tkcDRcL1NJamFuSDNXNzhZZTNOVkVHNllBWVEyV3EzaEs2WVMwa3NHZUdsIiwibWFjIjoiYzVlY2NhOGMzNjZiN2ZjOWRjMGE2ZTgzZTI1NGYyNmU4ZDU1MDUzY2FhZDQzMDEzZjI2YTI4ZGU1ZjIwOTBiNSJ9; ion_client_session=eyJpdiI6IjBpWlVsaXgxQVpDTVdCVjgrRHZuOVE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiWnNuemFxaStKdmlhK2dxMXppempKc1YwSm9IRkR0R0JLZzJzUVlpVXNZK2w2U3BvYm01aFIrQkxUc0hXckxrRCIsIm1hYyI6IjIwYjY1MTllYmNkOWJmNDM4ODJkNjY0ZjJjNTU2YzVmNDg4YTFmMGZhNWExMWM0MDYzMmI1Y2YzNWZiNjg0NjIifQ%3D%3D
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
```

**Response headers**

```
HTTP/2.0 200 OK
date: Sat, 01 Sep 2018 17:25:49 GMT
server: Apache
x-powered-by: PHP/7.2.9
content-disposition: attachment; filename=LMJgPLybBbZg1PiSpSJRAdWbH69bGF.zip
cache-control: no-cache, private
set-cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6Ik9iTENwOWlydkNJSTlkNmVoNm10SGc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiUG9ZQXNcL0k2dmlJZlVSZUpDUlZMU0JzMzNPWUZNTVpJSUs5XC85UnhRSFVLQUVDYmxKcXJQeTNIMVIxdjExNCtoIiwibWFjIjoiNzIwNWVjNmE3NzEwYmJiZjRjYzdlZmYzYTNmNmQwMDNlZjFmZmI4M2RmOTVmYTM4NTI1ZDA5ZDNlZGJmNzM0YiJ9; expires=Sat, 01-Sep-2018 19:25:50 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/
set-cookie: ion_client_session=eyJpdiI6IlVlWWJOa1FNOE8yeVIzamo4M2c5VEE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoid3R0QTZ0bEV3R1FXRzMwSUlcL0NDZGxEd1wveDFrZzdSWVRSejFDQkpaWVMrajVqNDJlNmZjUE9sWklPbHNrM2ZMIiwibWFjIjoiYTVhOGQ0NDg1ODY3MWU3MDBlYmFlYzA2MWYxYjQwMzhmMWExOGFlNWRjNDkyZTJhMjA0MTU1ZWVmZjhlOGZhYyJ9; expires=Sat, 01-Sep-2018 19:25:50 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly
content-length: 4216
content-type: application/zip
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
```

Comment: I believe this is firefox related issue, might get more help with the tag, actually it's looking more like a windows security thing @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12232722/1207346, are you downloading a dodgy exe masquerading as a zip #uDontHaq

Comment: It happens on chrome & firefox, and its a basic .zip with a .psd and a .png in it. I don't get the issue with some file types. I tested with images, .exe & .dll they all seem to work fine and not have any issues.

Comment: Most bizarre, it's not an issue I've run into myself but appears to be some form of money extraction technique by the big browser players

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed after Google crawlers verified my website.